# Python, Why is my script not running?

Tags: python

I've made a script to calculate the probability of a point in a tennis match, depending on the current score.

But for some reason when I want to run my script nothing happens. Explination is on the script.

Any suggestions?

```
    ## calculate the probability of server winning a single game, 
## given p(winning single point) and current point score

def fact(x):
    if x in [0, 1]:  return 1
    r = 1
    for a in range(1, (x+1)):  r = r*a
    return r

def ch(a, b):
    return fact(a)/(fact(b)*fact(a-b))

def gameOutcome(s, a, b):
    return ch((a+b), a)*(s**a)*((1-s)**b)*s

def gameProb(s=[0.6], v=2, w=1):
    ## function calculates the probability of server winning
    ## a single game, given p(winning any given point) [s],
    ## and the current point score.
    ## v, w = current game score, where love = 0, 15 = 1, etc.
    ## - e.g. 30-15 is v=2, w=1
    ## check if game is already over:
    if v >= 4 and (v-w) >= 2:
        return 1
    elif w >= 4 and (w-v) >= 2:
        return 0
    else:   pass
    ## if deuce or ad score e.g. 5-4, reduce to e.g. 3-2
    while True:
        if (v+w) > 6:
            v -= 1
            w -= 1
        else:   break
    ## specific probabilities:
    if w == 0:  w0 = gameOutcome(s, 3-v, 0)
    else:   w0 = 0
    if w <= 1:  w15 = gameOutcome(s, 3-v, 1-w)
    else:   w15 = 0
    if w <= 2:  w30 = gameOutcome(s, 3-v, 2-w)
    else:   w30 = 0
    if v == 4:
        wAd, lAd = s, 0
        d = 1-s
    elif w == 4:
        wAd, lAd = 0, 1-s
        d = s
    else:
        wAd, lAd = 0, 0
        a = 3 - v
        b = 3 - w
        d = ch((a+b), a)*(s**a)*((1-s)**b)
    if v <= 2:  l30 = gameOutcome((1-s), 3-w, 2-v)
    else:   l30 = 0
    if v <= 1:  l15 = gameOutcome((1-s), 3-w, 1-v)
    else:   l15 = 0
    if v == 0:  l0 = gameOutcome((1-s), 3-w, 0)
    else:   l0 = 0
    ## given d = prob of getting to deuce,
    ## math to divide up further outcomes
    denom = s**2 + (1-s)**2
    wd = (d*(s**2))/denom
    ld = (d*((1-s)**2))/denom
    win = w0 + w15 + w30 + wd + wAd
    lose = l0 + l15 + l30 + ld + lAd
    return win
```

Comment: `Return win` -> `return win` and to see the functions in action, you should call the appropriate function.

Comment: Becasue you aren't calling anything.

Comment: Your script consists of a bunch of function definitions. It doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: And for the love of god read PEP-8. PLease don't put you `if` blocks all on one line.

Comment: why did you make `s` a list?

Comment: @Orions, because I thought I had to. I'm still in my "newby" stage so any suggestions would be welcome

Comment: @IanAuld, I'm still very much a newby in Python. Thank you for your tip. I will read PEP-8 straight away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s` is a float, so, replace this line:

```
def gameProb(s=[0.6], v=2, w=1):
```

with

```
def gameProb(s=0.6, v=2, w=1):
```

and call the function at the end of the script:

```
print gameProb()
```

You can also call it as:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     print gameProb()
```

It makes your script a [*reusable module*](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/tutor-what-is-if-name-main-for.htm) which means you can import it inside another script without running the line `print gameProb()`.

Comment: and where do I call the function?

Answer (score 4):

Do you call the `gameProb` anywhere? Common practice is using this pattern:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    gameProb()
```

and make return lowercase.

Comment: ahead for one second :P

Comment: @PatNowak, where do I put the pattern mentioned by you?

Comment: At the end of the script.